# how to get client ip in asp core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, centos

I will get the client ip with _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()
but i got 127.0.0.1 or  ::1 .
my web server is nginx with follow setting :

```
 location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

my codes:
`_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();` that will return 127.0.0.1 or ::1
and i add follow codes to Configure method:

```
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is ok.

Are you launching you app from local? if so, `127.0.0.1` or `::1` would be ok. Because `127.0.0.1` or `::1` is your ip address.

If you've deployed your app to a remote server you wouldn't see `127.0.0.1`.

Note that you have to use `app.UseForwardedHeaders(...)` before middlewares which use the ip address:

```
//...
// use it here
//...
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints();
```

Comment: thanks,unfortunately in both mode(debug and deployed) its return 127.0.0.1

Comment: So, Make sure use are using `app.UseForwardedHeaders(...)` before other middlewares.

Comment: yes its set as first middleware,but still dosent work